# Excluding transitive dependency from Maven pom

Tags: maven, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

I have a Maven dependency added where type is `test-jar` and scope is `test`. I want to remove a transitive dependency from this (because in the Nexus prod repo this dependency is missing which leads to Jenkins build failure). I have added a exclusion tag but still the dependency is not removed i.e. Jenkins build still fails and complains about this dependency. Any clue why?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <version>${xxx.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jamon</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.jamonapi</groupId>
                <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What do you mean by: `but still the dependency is not removed`?

Comment: Please supply the relevant part(s) of your POM.

Comment: Maybe an other dependency brings this dependency by transitivity. Can not tell more without the pom file.

Comment: Question edited with POM snippet

Comment: I sugest you to use the command :  mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections to see who brings the transitive dependency (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Comment: Docs: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following command to find out the transitive dependency details and then you can exclude the dependency:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=<artifact_name>
```